# Is there a way to add badge on app icon without showing a notification?

Tags: android, notifications, badge

I've read about the notification badge icon [here](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/badges#set_custom_notification_count), but it is bound to a notification:

```
var notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this@MainActivity, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle("New Messages")
        .setContentText("You've received 3 new messages.")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_status)
        .setNumber(messageCount)
        .build()
```

Is there a way to change the count of the app badge icon to a customized number without showing a notification?

Comment: There is nothing in the Android SDK for what you seek. A few launchers supported private APIs for this, at least a few years ago.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, according to that documentation you can customize the badge count on Adroid 8.0 and higher (API 26+) and you already have it in your code;

```
.setNumber(messageCount)
```

`messageCount` is your customized number. Is this not working?

Comment: It needs to generate a notification right?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood what you are trying to do. No there is not a native way to do this. The closest solution may be, try to create a notification with setImportance(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN) priority, so it will not pop up to user's face, just sit in the tray silently.